# Oneliner: Why does this yield undefined is not a function?

Tags: javascript

Why does the following line sometimes yield the message "undefined is not a function" in the chrome dev console:

```
(callbackOrUndefined || function() {})();
```

The idea is to execute callback if it is truthy, i.e. a function, otherwise execute the empty function.

I had to replace it with :

```
if (callbackOrUndefined !== undefined) callbackOrUndefined();
```

Edit: I guess I wasn't clear enough. It sometimes seem to evaluate the block to undefined(); and I don't understand how and why.

Comment: Just me or `(callbackOrUndefined || function() {})();` returns a `ReferenceError: callbackOrUndefined is not defined`? You could try `(window.callbackOrUndefined || function() {})();`, for which the result is explained in the current answers.

Comment: True, which is why I made the assumption that the variable is declared somewhere but has not been given a value.

Comment: Following OP's edit, I have absolutely no idea what the question is about now. Maybe show what's the application of this or some code.

Comment: I think you're trying to be too tricky with your code.  I'd recommend: `if (typeof callbackOrUndefined == "function") {callbackOrUndefined();}` as a more foolproof and readable implementation.

Comment: +1 @jfriend00, that's most clear and readable way also.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté It looks like that `callbackOrUndefined` is the classic callback function passed as an argument, so it's already defined in the scope of the function.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. What doesn't make sense is OP's question. Well, time to call it a night, maybe tomorrow the question will make sense to me as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `callbackOrUndefined` has a falsy value and then the null function is selected, and when called, it returns `undefined`.

Notice that you may get `undefined` even if `callbackOrUndefined` doesn't return a defined value...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `callbackOrUndefined` is not defined. So its value is considered falsy. The `OR` then evaluates the empty function. The empty function doesnt return anything. The chrome dev console always prints the last returned value of whatever code you execute. In this case that is undefined.

BTW, doesnt it always return `undefined`. For it to not return `undefined`, `callbackOrUndefined` will need to have some truthy value.

Comment: No, a function pointer is a truthy value. So if callbackOrUndefined is set to a function, it executes that.

Comment: `callbackOrUndefined` *must* either have a falsy value of be a callable object, or else this would raise an exception.

Comment: How is what I said any different from what you guys are saying? He mentioned callbackOrUndefined being a passed in callback function only later. Without that info, it was safe to assume that it was undefined.

Comment: Because saying that `callbackOrUndefined` needs to have *some* truthy value is too generic: it cannot have every truthy value you want, it must be a callable object.